# walking through a LinkedList and deleting k elements, in O(n) time

Tags: java, algorithm

I am using Java's `LinkedList`, and as far as I know, there is no `LinkedList.next(int);`, but there is `ListIterator.next()`, which comes into play via `LinkedList.listIterator()`. However, as I figured out: using `ListIterator` to walk over the elements (which takes O(n) time) will fail after you delete all of them (a constant-time operation on the deletion itself, but O(n) to get to the element).

Trying to delete some k <= n elements the straightforward way, which is something like:

```
if (list.get(++index).equals(elementToRemove))
{
    list.remove(index);
}
```

is an O(n^2) operation, as each of the n `get()`s is O(n).

Is there any way to, in linear time, walk through the `LinkedList` and delete the elements that should go?

Comment: You have to use the iterator's `remove` method.

Comment: I'm confused, why wouldn't you use `ListIterator`?

Comment: I didn't know ListIterator had remove()!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--):

```
for (Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    T element = iterator.next();
    if (element.equals(elementToRemove)) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about in-place processing you can just use

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

function and then iterate over the table adding only desired items to new list